# PdfFilePrinter.Print still launches the Adobe Acrobat reader even if CreateNoWindow is true

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

somehow, with Adobe Acrobat X, PdfFilePrinter cannot prevent Adobe from silently printing PDF pages.

here's my code:

```
PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = PDFExecPath;
var printer = new PdfFilePrinter(this.documentPath, this.printer);
printer.Print();
```

here's the PdfSharp's source:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = PdfFilePrinter.adobeReaderPath;
string args = String.Format("/t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", this.pdfFileName, this.printerName);
//Debug.WriteLine(args);
startInfo.Arguments = args;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
if (this.workingDirectory != null && this.workingDirectory.Length != 0)
  startInfo.WorkingDirectory = this.workingDirectory;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved:

```
PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = PDFExecPath;
var printer = new PdfFilePrinter(this.documentPath, this.printer);
printer.Print(1000);
```

The Print(int milliseconds) overload kills the adobe acrobat program.

Comment: That did diddly squat for me.